# Pyinstaller is not recognized as an external or internal command, an executable program or a command file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a python program that prints "hello world !" with the Pyinstaller module. But when I type the command `pyinstaller HelloWorld.py`in my command prompt, it told me "pyinstaller is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a command file". How can I make compilation works correctly ?

Thank you !

In the HelloWorld.py file, I typed the following command :

`print("Hello World !")`

In the command prompt, I typed :
`pyinstaller HelloWorld.py`

This is when I hit the "Enter" key that the error happens.

Comment: did you install pyinstaller using pip?

Comment: First you have to `pip install pyinstaller`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've already installed Pyinstaller with pip. But when I'm trying to use it, my command prompt display the error. But when I use it, I am in the same folder than the file. I also tried to compile the file from a script, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can install it using pip.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

**Requirements**:

1. 3.7-3.11. Note that Python 3.10.0 contains a bug making it unsupportable by PyInstaller. PyInstaller will also not work with beta releases of Python 3.12.
2. PyInstaller should work on Windows 7 or newer, but it only officially support Windows 8+.
3. Support for Python installed from the Windows store without using virtual environments requires PyInstaller 4.4 or later.
4. Note that Windows on arm64 is not yet supported.

Comment: OK, so just because I'm using Python 3.10 on my Windows 10 PC, I can't use this librairy ? Are there other librairies like this one whiches works better on recent software config ?

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my issue.
PyInstaller --version throws errors as though PyInstaller was not recognized ....etc. Even if I tried editing the environment variables for the Path. So, I Uninstalled Python 3.11... Used some cleaning apps to clean my PC from as many remnants of python files, ..., etc. Deleted PyInstaller5.x, ....etc. Reinstalled a different version of Python (3.10.9) Edited the Environment Variables path to where PyInstaller is installed. And used pip install PyInstaller,...., Thank God! It now works. CHANGING THE VERSIONS SOLVED THE ISSUE. (Anti Virus was stopped in case)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).